# Convert C# Dictionary to multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert `Dictionary<string, string>` to *multidimensional array*.
The items inside multidimentional array should be in quotes.
So far I get this ["[mary, online]","[alex, offline]"].
But the output should be something like [["mary", "online"], ["alex", "offline"]]. Please help.

```
public void sendUpdatedUserlist(IDictionary<string, string> message)
{
    string[] array = message
      .Select(item => string.Format("[{0}, {1}]", item.Key, item.Value))
     .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a multidimensional array like `string[,]` or a jagged array like `string[][]`?

Comment: Instead of `string.Format` do `new string[]{ item.key,item.value}` ?

Comment: You should probably use a real JSON serializer for this. Will save you from fighting a bunch of edge case bugs and probably run faster as a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on **2d** array (`string[,]`, not *jagged* `string[][]`) you can create the array and fill it row by row:

```
string[,] array = new string[message.Count, 2];

int index = 0;

foreach (var pair in message) {
  array[index, 0] = pair.Key;
  array[index++, 1] = pair.Value; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.Format` isn't going to return an array, you're close, but what you want is to "select" an *actual* array.  Something like this:

```
var arr = dict.Select(kvp => new[] { kvp.Key, kvp.Value }).ToArray();
```

this is going to return type of `string[][]`, which is technically a jagged array (unlike a *true* 2D array `string[,]` in that each dimension doesn't have to be the same size) unlike the one-dimensional `string[]` you have declared in your sample code.

If you truly need a 2D array, you can't really do that with LINQ and `.ToArray()`, you'll have to populate it yourself with a loop.